# CLI Service Creation: Service Broker Timed Out (FAILED Server error, status code: 504, error code: 10001...)

Tags: command-line-interface, cloudant

The service creation fails, any idea why is failing?

Executed the following CLI command:

```
cf cs cloudantNoSQLDB Shared MICloudant
```

Response:

> Creating service instance MICloudant in org org-name / space  workshop
>   as ...

Result:

> FAILED Server error, status code: 504, error code: 10001, message: The
>   request to the service broker timed out:
>   https://provision-broker.ng.bluemix.net/bmx/provisioning/brokers/ab25b9d1-717a-4720-a538-30f41b817cf5/v2/service_instances/7bc4ba63-970c-449d-8117-1ec60da3782e?accepts_incomplete=true

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same command again this morning (nothing was changed) but this time worked. Have you encountered this behavior before? Does the broker times out often? Anyway, thanks. Cheers, A.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue. First time, I gave wrong domain name in host. Because of wrong domain, CC could able to find the domain to create the service.

Second time, I gave correct domain name for my host. CC found the domain and created service instance for my service.